# How to catch Ctrl+C event on multithreads .NET program in a portable way

Tags: .net, multithreading, f#, mono

I'm trying to implement a program that intercept the Ctrl+C event in order to do some clean-up operations. This is an example code:

```
open System
open System.Threading

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let start() =
        async {
            while true do
                let rnd = new Random()
                let timeout = rnd.Next(1000, 3000)
                Thread.Sleep(timeout)
                Console.Write('.')
        }

    Console.CancelKeyPress.Add(fun _ -> Console.WriteLine("In Ctrl+C event handler"))

    for i = 0 to 30 do
        start() |> Async.Start

    Thread.Sleep(-1)

    0
```

unfortunately in this situation the handler is never called. I have resolved the problem by going native and using the SetConsoleCtrlHandler method as described [here](http://www.fssnip.net/2k).

Unfortunately even if now it works, this solution is not portable on other OS.

How can I intercept the Ctrl+C event in a multithreading program using a portable solution?